# Remove specific fields from email woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Im using Woocomerce and some fields are being added automatically. I want to remove some of this, but, when I'm editing the template, I can't figure out what function or part of the code I need edit, I will post an image from the email:

[image: I want just the Tracking Number and Date Shipped, I want to REMOVE Status, Provider, Tracking Link]

I want just the Tracking Number and Date Shipped and I want to REMOVE Status, Provider, Tracking Link

And this is the code of template:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Customer completed order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Site title */ ?>
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'We have finished processing your order.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
<?php

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.
 */
if ( $additional_content ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Comment: Could you tell what fields you want to remove?

Comment: Yes, I put in the post but its not there anymore, I will edit, but, I want remove: Fullfilment Status, Provider and Tracking Link.

Comment: Try using *vardump()* on the variable *$plain_text* to see what data you get.

Comment: do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', var_dump($order), $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

And I get:

 { ["current_data":protected]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(35446) ["key"]=> string(15) "Tracking Number" ["value"]=> string(13) "LO737780564CN" } ["data":protected]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(35446) ["key"]=> string(15) "Tracking Number" ["value"]=> string(13) "LO7377805CN" } } [4]=> object(WC_Meta_Data)#17649 (2) { ["current_data":protected]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(35447) ["key"]=> string(13) "Tracking Link" ["value"]=> string(40) "http://track.aftership.com/LO7377805CN" }

Comment: Then it seems like that part of the code you are looking for is not in this file.

Comment: Yes, and I still cant edit

Answer (score 0):

After some work, i figure out this solution:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
$item->delete_meta_data('Provider');
$item->delete_meta_data('Tracking Link');
```

}

Works